# How to add a certain parameter (ad_id) to URL?

Tags: google-search-console, url, url-parameters

On my WordPress site, there is a page `http://www.example.com/doc/list/` that dynamically shows all DB entries (76,000).

Google does not index the different entries. The URLs looks like this `http://www.example.com/doc/list/44444/name/`.

How can I tell Google that the `/44444/` is the parameter that makes the content unique, even if the name is the same?

I read the Google Webmaster Tools help for URL Parameters, but don't understand how that applies to my problem.   So far I am not able to produce a sitemap that contains all these URLs with available plugins.

Comment: The question in the title seems to be different to the question in the body.

Answer (score 1):

To Google, `http://www.example.com/doc/list/44444/name/` is a different URL from `http://www.example.com/doc/list/44445/name/`.  If it finds links to both of them it will crawl both of them and index both of them.

Google automatically assumes that any difference in a URL makes the page different and this it should crawl and index all different variations.  You start running into problems when you have the same content on slightly different URLs and have to tell Googlebot about which one is the "canonical" one that you want indexed.

Google webmaster tools URL parameters won't help in this case.  URL parameters are name value pairs that come after the question mark.  Google lets you specify which names of those don't change the page content for things like tracking parameters: `/folder/page.html?sessionid=9382738`.   But as I mentioned earlier, you don't need to take any action anyway.